# What could be causing this error : "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232576

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, msbuild

this error (**C:\Builds\7\BoothApplications\VS2017_LeadApplication_DEV\src\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets (84): "csc.exe" exited with code -214623257**) is causing me a lot of trouble while I attempt to do my msbuild. I have reloaded the nuget packages Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.6.1, I have reloaded Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset 3.7.0. Also, I loaded Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 3.6.0 nothing is working. I need to get this msbuild working. Note: the solution builds locally and it can be published using the file share, but I want to perform a Web Deploy. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.